# Implementing search bar without using searchable activity

Tags: android, listview, search, android-actionbar, optionmenu

Is it possible to implement a search bar (with EditText) on OptionMenu and add a TextChangedListener to it? 
My MainActivity have 3 swipeable tabs with 3 different ListView so I'm thinking about adding a TextChangedListener for a EditText on ActionBar (if possible) would be a better choice instead of creating Searchable Activity. Then, I can easily get current ListView and filter it with the text in SearchBar like the example below. However, his EditText is not on ActionBar.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Simply inflate such a menu in your activity:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"  app:actionLayout="@layout/action_item_edit_text"
         app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

action_item_edit_text.xml

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editInput"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:hint="Write something"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:padding="6dp"/>
```

Then you can get reference to edit text in `onCreateOptionsMenu` through:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings));
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { \\... });
```